# Angular 17 mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl, but NOT using MatForm

Tags: angular-material, angular17

I am using Angular v17, and I do have Angular Materials v17 installed.

I have a page, giving me the dreaded 'mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl'

However, that page has no Mat Form Control or Mat Form Field on it.  Nor button, list or any other material.

In fact, in an effort to trouble shoot this, I made sure nothing in the project imports MatFormField or MatFormControl

So I give up.  Where is this coming from?  I'm unclear how to even trouble shoot this?
I get that the stack trace CLEARLY shows MatFormField, but I am not importing it.  How is the trace showing that MatFormfield is being called, when I am not even importing it?

```
Stack: Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:110505:12)
    at MatFormField._validateControlChild (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:111016:19)
    at MatFormField.ngAfterContentChecked (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:110839:14)
    at callProviderLifecycles /main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:87448:18)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:87417:13)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:87399:29)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:88619:5)
    at callViewAction (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:88980:21)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:88937:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/main.c8813ac251e233ee557e.js:88615:5)
```

These are the only imports I am using:

```
    MatIconModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule
```

Comment: please share the github repo if its public!, try checking the stack trace from development environment, it will give you the location of where this error is coming from!

Comment: Sorry, it's proprietary code that I do not have permission to share.
I have never been able to recreate it in debug mode.  It only happens in release mode